# Forcast Linear in Excel works?

Tags: excel

I am working in predict value in the upcoming year,by using FORCAST.LINEAR build in function in excel. However, I don't know how to interpret the result from this function. Anyone could explain me how statistic function in excel; FORCAST.LINEAR, work? which detail formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website explains it well:

https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/functions/forecast-linear-function/

Let us know in the comments if you need more help.